# Relative paths in *.sln *.csproj files of c# .NetStandard project

Tags: c#, .net-standard

Basically what the titles says. I have a .NetStandard library which I am working on from both windows and linux. My issue is that the reference paths are fully specified.

Let's say in this case, I have 4 projects, each with their own folder and git repository. Project 1 references Project 2, 3, and 4; Project 2 and 3 reference project 4. The project folder structure is the same on both linux and windows however the user profile path variable differs.

|-Project 1 
|
|-Project 2
|
|-Project 3
|
|-Project 4

Can I specify relative paths in the .sln and .csproj files? If so how?

Comment: The question is confusing. I'm not sure whet is your problem. But to the question. I have only relative paths in `*.sln` and `*.csproj` files *(mostly to current directory)*.

Comment: @Christopher Not sure where that comment is headed, but it is completely irrelevant to what the OP is asking. Do you even know what .NET Standard is? If so, why are you mentioning Mono and Xamarin? Those are different beasts

Comment: @Christopher The title says .NET Standard. There's not a single mention of .NET Framework. Please read the question

Comment: @Christopher I am not using Core , Mono , or Framework but I think that is besides the point anyway since this issue is related to how the c# compilers use *.sln anc *.csproj files, and not so much what framework I am targeting.

Comment: Could you add some lines from your .proj and .sln files that clarify what is causing problems. I went ahead and posted an answer with lines from my .csproj and .sln but it seems like something else is going on with your issue because relative paths are generated by visual studio in our csproj and sln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put paths that are relative to the .sln or .*proj in their respective files. I just opened up the .sln and .*proj our company is using an it looks like this. These were auto generated by Visual Studio for us when adding projects to the solution.

**.sln**

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "BL", "BL\BL.csproj", "{DF73AB2C-7331-49FD-8B4A-F71DAC66198A}"
EndProject
```

**.*proj**

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\BL\BL.csproj">
  <Project>{df73ab2c-7331-49fd-8b4a-f71dac66198a}</Project>
  <Name>BL</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Comment: Be careful by using `..` inside a csproj file, you are not sure where you start from. E.g. the behavior is different from inside Visual Studio and Command Line (msbuild). I would suggest use `$(ProjectDir)` or `$(SolutionDir)` before `..` to be sure where you come from.

Answer (score 1):

In `*.csproj` you can define properties.

Define a property `MyStuffDir` with the value `$(ProjectDir)..\..\_MyFolder\`.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyStuffDir>$(ProjectDir)..\..\_MyFolder\</MyStuffDir>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

`$(ProjectDir)` is the folder where the current `csproj-file` is placed. Much more "Macros" available, see for example Build Events "PreBuildSteps" and "PostBuildSteps". `$(SolutionDir)` is where the `sln-file` is placed.

**HINT** I prefer the usage of `$(ProjectDir)`, because it works also on CLI with msbuild, when I just build a single project and not the whole solution.

Use `$(MyStuffDir)` inside an item group of the csproj-file, so you are relative to project level.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(MyStuffDir)AssemblyVersion.cs">
      <Link>Properties\AssemblyVersion.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```